# Function with fetch returns undefined instead an array (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, fetch

I have a file with some functions:

```
const API = {
async getComments() {
   var data = [];
   var url = 'http://url.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments';
   const serviceResponse = await fetch(
    url,
    )
    .then((serviceResponse) => {
     return serviceResponse.json();
   } )
    .catch((error) => console.warn("fetch error:", error))
    .then((serviceResponse) => {
      for (i in serviceResponse) {
        data.push({
         "key": serviceResponse[i]['id'].toString(),
         "name": serviceResponse[i]['author_name'],
         "content": serviceResponse[i]['content']['rendered'].replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, ''),
         "gravatar": serviceResponse[i]['author_avatar_urls']['96'],
         "date": serviceResponse[i]['date'].replace('T', ' ')
        });
      }
      global.comments = data;
      return data;
   });
 }
}

export { API as default }
```

In another file I include the file, and make the call:

```
var comments = await API.getComments(key);
console.log (comments);
```

But I receive undefined, I tried to create a function with bind:
this.newGetComments = API.getComments.bind(this); with the same result. I used a global variable, but I want to remove the globals vars.

Comment: Hi @Enrique, what you have received undefined. `global` variable? or `getComments()` ?

Comment: You forgot to return data in `getComments`. Try return `serviceResponse` at the end of `getComments`

Comment: Thank you, I had the return in a wrong line, sorry I didn't see that detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/* Few suggestions;
1. you  are not returning anything from the getComments method. Please return fetch(url) response.
2. you should return  something from the catch block to handle the error.
*/


const API = {
  async getComments() {
    var url = 'http://url.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments';
    var response = await fetch(url)
      .then(serviceResponse => {
        return serviceResponse.json();
      })
      .then(serviceResponse => {
        let data = [];
        
        // rest of your code.
        
        return { success: true, data };
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.warn('fetch error:', error);
        return { success: false, error };
      });
    return response
  },
};

var comments = await API.getComments(key);
if (comments.success) {
  // handle the success case  comments.data
} else {
  // handle the Error case  comments.error
}

console.log(comments);
```

Comment: I am sorry, yes the return was in a wrong line, thank you.
I'll add a response in error case

Answer (score 0):

An async function always returns a promise as you aren't returning anything from the getComments methods, the function automatically resolves and returns undefined(Promise.resolve(undefined)). You need to return serviceResponse from the getComments method to get the fetch api's response.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

```
async componentDidMount() {
   let data = [];
   const result = await this.getComments();
   const jsonData = await result.json();
   console.log('Result ==> ', jsonData.serviceResponse);

   jsonData.serviceResponse.map(data => 
      data.push({
                 "key": data['id'].toString(),
                 "name": data[i]['author_name'],
                 "content": data[i]['content']['rendered'].replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, ''),
                 "gravatar": data[i]['author_avatar_urls']['96'],
                 "date": data[i]['date'].replace('T', ' ')
               })
   );
   console.log('Data ==> ', data);
}

async getComments() {
   const result = await fetch('http://url.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments', {method: 'GET'});
   return result;
}
```